# Go to a specific slide in powerpoint when creating the slides

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

This might be very simple to achieve, but I don't know how to see it through.
When I create presentations using MS powerpoint, I have to go from slide to slide (say from Slide 3 to slide 45). So far I have reached the required slide using the slide sorter.

For a similar requirement, MS Word has the option of `Go to page` which can be called using `Ctrl+G` keyboard shortcut.

Is there a similar shortcut to go to a particular slide while editing slides in MS powerpoint?

**Update**

From the answer below and from the internet search I understand that in *Edit mode* one cannot go to a particular slide (as one would go to a page in Word).

I wrote the following macro to implement this functionality.

```
'Go to a particular slide when in edit mode
Sub go_to_slide()
Dim S As Integer
Dim total_slides As Integer
total_slides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
S = InputBox("Enter slide number", "Go To Slide")
If (S <= 0) Then
MsgBox ("Enter slide number greater than zero")
ElseIf (S > total_slides) Then
MsgBox ("Enter slide number less than the total slides")
ElseIf (S <= total_slides) Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(S).Select
End If
End Sub
```

Is there a better/efficient way to implement this?

Comment: I think Benson Yeung's method below is enough.(if you haven't seen it..)

Answer (score 10):

#### Is there a shortcut to go to a particular slide in the presentation?

Presentation mode:

- <kbd>*Slide number*</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or
- <kbd>Right-click</kbd> a slide, select "Go to Slide" on the shortcut menu, and then select a slide from the list by *title* or *slide number*.

Edit mode:

- There is no function to navigate quickly to a specific slide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question with macro

Answer (score 10):

I just came across the same issue. For example to go to slide 60, my solution is to enter the presentation mode and go back to editing mode immediately afterwards: `<F5> 60 <Enter> <Esc>`.  A few more keystrokes but fast enough and working well for me.

F5: presentation mode

60: the desired slide number

Enter: go to slide

Esc: back to edit mode, on the shown slide

Answer (score 3):

@Prasanna, thank you for your code, which didn't work for me but got me started.

This version works for me. I wish I knew how to assign a keyboard command (hotkey) to it.

```
Sub go_to_slide() 'Go to a particular slide when in edit mode. Adapted from https://superuser.com/q/1174096/74576
    Dim slide_num As Integer
    Dim total_slides As Integer
    total_slides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    slide_num = InputBox("Enter slide number between 1 and " & total_slides, "Go To Slide")
    If ((slide_num <= 0) Or (slide_num > total_slides)) Then
        go_to_slide
    ElseIf (slide_num <= total_slides) Then
        'MsgBox ("Jumping to slide #" & slide_num)
        ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide slide_num
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cant believe PowerPoint does not have this shortcut..
If you use autohotkey this is an excellent workaround (if not then you should reconsider! :-) ). Activated using CTRL+G (for go)

```
;go to slide in PowerPoint
#IfWinActive PowerPoint
    ^G::
    InputBox, UserInput, Go to Slide Number, Please enter a slide number., , 200, 150
    Send, {F5}
    sleep, 100
    Send, %UserInput%
    Send, {Enter}
    sleep, 250
    Send, {Esc}
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the text you want to use as link to a certain slide
2. go to insert -> links-> action
3. select hyperlink to -> select slide

this link now works when editing powerpoint and during the presentation itself

Answer (score 0):

That,s the way to go about it:
To go to a particular slide in the same presentation select a word in the slide to be hyperlinked. In the left selection bar "Link to": Select "place in this document". this will show you the slide numbers on the right. Select the one you want to go to. Works perfect!

Answer (score -1):

I use the same 'link' technique on images, icons, whole shapes/text boxes etc. Usually a little 'Play' triangle button on the bottom right of the slide.

Then I add the same icon on the page I 'jump' to with a link that sends me back too. If you animate this icon so that it only appears at the end of all animations in that slide, the presenter can keep clicking the mouse button from the source slide 'play button' through these animations and then jump back without needing to move the mouse/cursor.

Helps when other people will use the deck....defence against ID-10-t errors! ;-)